# Is it impossible to start a Activity in UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android

I found that it not works when start a new activity in UncaughtExceptionHandler. What I mean to do is not to show the annoying Android crash dialog. On the other hand, I want to start a new activity to indicate user that we encounter a serious error, do U wanna quit or continue to use the APP still with the possibility that something weird may happen.

I even try to restart the APP in UncaughtExceptionHandler by

```
final Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());  
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
    startActivity(intent);
```

but, I'm in bad luck again. It not work either...

Answer (score 2):

I tried this to restart my App after crashed happens. I catched all uncaught exceptions in your Application extension class. In the exception handler do something about exception and try to set up AlarmManager to restart my app. Here is example how I do it in my app, but I only log exception to a db.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    // uncaught exception handler variable
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

    // handler listener
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler =
        new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

                // here I do logging of exception to a db
                PendingIntent myActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(),
                    192837, new Intent(getContext(), MyActivity.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager;
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                    15000, myActivity );
                System.exit(2);

                // re-throw critical exception further to the os (important)
                defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        };

    public MyApplication() {
        defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

        // setup handler for uncaught exception 
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start `PendingIntent` with `AlarmManager`.

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 12345, new Intent(context,
                    startActivity).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, pi);
```

Place value for `context` variable in constructor of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use(post-delayed) a thread.

EDIT: or `Thread.sleep`

```
@Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        this.ex = e;
        try {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                            .getClassName
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            context.getString(R.string.uncaught_exception),
                            Constants.ToastDuration).show();
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            }.start();

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Intent errorIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            errorIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(errorIntent);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1); //OPTIONAL and not suggested not to be followed
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            CommonUtil.logMessage(LOG,(Exception) exc);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            CommonUtil.logMessage(LOG,(Exception) ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of @SilentKnight s Version

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
// uncaught exception handler variable
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

// handler listener
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler =
        new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                //get stack trace
                //get error stacktrace
                String _OSVERSION = System.getProperty("os.version");
                String _RELEASE = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
                String _DEVICE = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
                String _MODEL = android.os.Build.MODEL;
                String _PRODUCT = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
                String _BRAND = android.os.Build.BRAND;
                String _DISPLAY = android.os.Build.DISPLAY;
                String _CPU_ABI = android.os.Build.CPU_ABI;
                String _CPU_ABI2 = android.os.Build.CPU_ABI2;
                String _UNKNOWN = android.os.Build.UNKNOWN;
                String _HARDWARE = android.os.Build.HARDWARE;
                String _ID = android.os.Build.ID;
                String _MANUFACTURER = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
                String _SERIAL = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
                String _USER = android.os.Build.USER;
                String _HOST = android.os.Build.HOST;
                String all = String.format("os:%s\nrelease:%s\ndev:%s\nmodel:%s\nprod:%s\nbrand:%s\ndisp:%s\ncpu_abi:%s\n" +
                                "cpu_abi2:%s\nunknown:%s\nhardware:%s\nid:%s\nmanu:%s\nserial:%s\nhost:%s\nuser:%s\n",
                        _OSVERSION, _RELEASE, _DEVICE, _MODEL, _PRODUCT, _BRAND, _DISPLAY, _CPU_ABI,
                        _CPU_ABI2, _UNKNOWN, _HARDWARE, _ID, _MANUFACTURER, _SERIAL, _HOST, _USER);
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                String st = String.format("Process down\nTime: %s [%s]\n\nDev infos:\n%s\nStacktraces...\n\n", convertTime(time), time, all);
                for(StackTraceElement e : ex.getStackTrace())
                    st += "\n" + String.format("%s> %s (=%s); [%s]; {%s}", e.getLineNumber(), e.getClassName(), e.getFileName(), e.getMethodName(), e.isNativeMethod());

                //and write it to file
                FileManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), String.format("logs/%s.str", time)).write(st);

                //create the intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Killed.class);
                intent.putExtra("log", st);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                // here I do logging of exception to a db
                PendingIntent myActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                        192837, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                AlarmManager alarmManager;
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        15000, myActivity);
                System.exit(2);

                // re-throw critical exception further to the os (important)
                defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        };

public String convertTime(long time){
    Date date = new Date(time);
    Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
    return format.format(date);
}

public MyApplication() {
    defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    // setup handler for uncaught exception
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```

}

another helpful class could be a log shower:

```
public class Killed extends LActivity
```

{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    hsv.addView(sv);
    sv.addView(tv);

    setContentView(hsv);

    final String log = getIntent().getStringExtra("log");
    tv.setText(log);
    tv.setTextIsSelectable(true);

    tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","developer@gmail.com", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Error log: MyApp");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, log);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}